# Sum of residuals in NLS regression are not close to zero

Tags: r, nls

I am running a NLS model in R. The residuals are normally distributed, but the mean of the residuals are not zero. How is this possible?

```
x <- data.frame( height= c(185, 194,166, 187, 181,177),
           weight=c(77,67,79,87,65,64),
            age=c(76,89,76,43,56,54))


model <- nls(height ~ a*weight + age*c, data=x, start= list(a=0, c=0))

residuals <- x$height - predict(model,x)
sum(residuals)
```

Comment: We need to see code and data, please edit the question with the code you've tried and the output of `dput(head(df, 30))`. How far from zero is the residuals mean?

Comment: `resid(model)` will give the residuals.

Answer (score 2):

Its the intercept .... i think u need an intercept to get the algebra to work properly...

Comment: Why are you using `nls`? Your model is currently the same as `lm(height ~ weight + age + 0, data = x)`, and if you remove the `0` this will include the intercept.

Comment: Its an example.. in my model i need control some of the estimators...(lm gives completly meaningless results)